# Does Foreign Key constraint need to include NOT EQUAL to sibling Foreign Key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and Postgresql. I am trying to better understand how a foreign key constraint works with primary key of parent table.

Here's my current setup for two tables. I am trying to mimic an ISA relationship where echecks IS-A payment.

```
Table "public.payments"
Column |         Type          |                       Modifiers                        

pid    | integer               | not null default nextval('payments_pid_seq'::regclass)
street | character varying(80) | 
zip    | integer               | 
Indexes:
"payments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pid)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "cards" CONSTRAINT "cards_pid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES payments(pid)
    TABLE "echecks" CONSTRAINT "echecks_pid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES payments(pid)


Table "public.echecks"
  Column   |         Type          | Modifiers 

rtgacctnum | bigint                | 
accttype   | character varying(80) | 
nameonacct | character varying(80) | 
pid        | integer               | not null default nextval('payments_pid_seq'::regclass)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "echecks_pid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES payments(pid)


Table "public.cards"
  Column   |         Type          |                      Modifiers                      
pid        | integer               | not null default nextval('cards_pid_seq'::regclass)
cnum       | bigint                | 
nameoncard | character varying(80) | 
Foreign-key constraints:
"cards_pid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES payments(pid)
```

With this current setup, I am not able to prevent Echecks and Cards from inheriting the same pid from payments. I want Echecks to use the next number available pid from Payments, *and* not be the same pid in Cards.

Simplified version of what I would like to have happen:

```
Payments(pid, pay_type):
1, paypal
2, echeck
3, credit card
4, echeck

Echecks(fk_pid, acct_name)
2, susy
4, bob

Cards(fk_pid, card_name)
3, john
```

Instead, Echecks is just assigning on insertion:

```
1, susy
2, bob
```

And Cards assigns:

```
1, john
```

What is the best way to setup constraints on the foreign keys to insure it's being assigned a unique pid from Payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echecks is not "grabbing" any value. You're supposed to insert a value into it that you want to appear there. So your real problem lies within insert logic that you didn't include in your post.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did leave that important piece out. So I would like to be able to `INSERT INTO echecks(acctnum, type, nameonacct) VALUES (123456, 'checking' , 'susy');` and have the pid auto-assigned using the proper unique pid from Payments and not in Cards.

Comment: FKs don't have anything to do with autoinsertion of values.You can't expect it to figure it out, you have to tell it what to do.

Comment: @runit But what will the row in Payments have in it? You have to insert something there, right? Checkout this about how to insert into two tables having fk reference at the same time: http://www.depesz.com/2011/03/16/waiting-for-9-1-writable-cte/